# What exactly is returned by .class in Java?

Tags: java, class

Why is it not allowed to call the static method through the class reference returned by **.class** ? But instead if static method is called directly using class name it works fine. Like in example below. Are they not equal ?

```
package typeinfo;

class Base {
    public static void method1() {
        System.out.println("Inside static method1");
    }
    public void method2() {
        System.out.println("Inside method2");
    }
}
public class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<Base> b = Base.class;
        // Works fine
        Base.method1();
        // Gives compilation error: cannot find symbol
        // Is below statement not equal to Base.method1() ?
        b.method1();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.class` returns an instance of class `java.lang.Class` - and no, `Class<Base>` is not the same as `Base`.

Class `java.lang.Class` is mainly used when you use the [Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But why Class<Base> is not equal to Base ?

Comment: They are names of different types - the type `java.lang.Class` and the type `typeinfo.Base`. As Eran says, the object of type `Class<Base>` has the methods of class `Class`, and not the methods of class `Base`, so you can't call methods of class `Base` on the object that is of type `Class`.

Answer (score 3):

`b` is of type `Class`, so it has the methods of the [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) type, and not the methods of your `Base` class.

You can use instances of `Class` to invoke methods of the classes they refer to via reflection.

Answer (score 1):

`Base` is class *name*. `Base.method()` is java syntax for invoking a static method on class `Base`.

`Base.class` is a reference to an object of type `Class`, describing the class `Base`. `Base.class.method1()` does not work of course, because class `Class` does not have a method `method1`.

You can call methods of underlying class if you have to, using reflection. Consider:

`Base.class.getMethod("method1").invoke(null);`